# How many digits does the integer have?

Tags: arithmetic

We choose two numbers between $0$ and $9$, and the sum of the numbers should not be $9$.  In addition, we cannot choose a number which we have already taken.  How many digits does the sum have at most?

Comment: Can I choose 8 and 9? Then the sum is at most of two digit?

Comment: I have answered the asked question, but I wonder if it's what you intended. My answer has nothing to do with probability and doesn't use any of the assumptions of the problem other than "between $0$ and $9$"

Comment: Well, the sum can not exceed $9+9=18$.

Comment: I choose $e$ and $\pi$, with an infinite number of digits.

Comment: @Joffan,sir, the question is," How namy digits does the interger have?"

Comment: What a bizarre question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum of two one digit number is clearly less than $100$ and so cannot have $3$ digits. $6+5=11$ demonstrates that there can be $2$ digits, and so the answer is $2$.